# Slider fadein/fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this slider for my website but I need to apply a `fadeIn/out` when go `next/prev`. Can anyone explain me how to do this or show me the code?

**JS**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x150" style="display:none">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x100" style="display:none">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x200" style="display:none">
    <button onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Argon answer make a better design just for that

Comment: The absolute position move all my elements. Argon didnt touch the style for that i accepted his answer

Comment: Without css the onclick show the first slide fading into the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can replace this:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";   
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

With this:

```
$('.mySlides:visible').fadeOut(function() {
   $(x[slideIndex-1]).fadeIn();
});
```

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  $('.mySlides:visible').fadeOut(function() {
     $(x[slideIndex-1]).fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x150" style="display:none">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x100" style="display:none">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/600x200" style="display:none">

      <button onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```